# Failed to launch chrome in puppeteer node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, puppeteer

I uploaded my code on EC2 aws. After uploading on ec2. It did not working.It is working correctly on localhost.I have tested many ways.Please suggest me the right way.
This is the screenshot of cmd.

[image]

Comment: It tells you where to go and what to do. You haven't provided us with any information whatsoever.

Comment: click on the given link and see the information.

Comment: Read the line starting with **TROUBLESHOOTING**.

Comment: It did not working.I have test already.After that i uploaded here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error clearly mentions that it can not find `libX11-xcb.so.1`. A simple Google search showed this:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
```

I hope it solves it.

Comment: What are you trying to do?